# Trimble RTK Data to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, trimble

I wondering if there is a way I can take my field data collected on a Trimble R10 RTK GPS and import it into ArcMap for further processing, I have done some research and I know of Trimble GPS Pathfinder Software, is this the only way?

If there is a way to bring it into Quantum, that would also be alternatively helpful.

Thanks Always

Answer (score 1):

I am not in a position to provide you the exact workflow but it must be possible. I believe you would have access to Trimble Business Center (TBC) application which is provided along with Trimble GNSS receivers. Once you post-process your data you would be able to export it into commonly used GIS formats like shapefiles. This exported data can be used effectively in ArcGIS or QGIS.